# E: Command line option 'V' [from -V] is not known

Tags: command-line, apt

Getting this error while running `apt-get --yes -V -c $CONF_FILE update` command.
This error is coming with ubuntu 14.04 only. For earlier version is working fine. 
Man page says :

```
-V, --verbose-versions
       Show full versions for upgraded and installed packages.
       Configuration Item: APT::Get::Show-Versions.
```

What is this `APT::Get::Show-Versions`? and how to configure.

I want `-V` to be working the way it was working in earlier version.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "-V" will work with "upgrade". "update" will not show any package versions, so I guess isn't useful anyway. Or... did I miss something?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

The `-V` option is not meant to be used with the `update` command. Only `upgrade` or `install` allow this option:

> Quite a while ago I wanted to ability to show the versions of packages
>   as they get upgraded.  It makes a great deal of difference to me if a
>   package is updating from 1-3 to 1-4 vrs 1-3 to 2-1.  The attached
>   patch provides an option to print verbose versions on **installs** or
>   **upgrades**. It uses the command line option `-V` or `--verbose-versions` or
>   the config item `APT::Get::Show-Versions`.

Source: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=131779